# how to change the order of fields?

Tags: php, drupal

When i manage the fields (Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Article » Manage Fields), change the sort of fields.

In database , where store the weight of the fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight is in "data" column of "field_config_instance" table. Note that data column stores a serialized array. As an example, here is the data column of one of the fields in my database. I have highlighted the weight field in bold. You will notice that each view mode also has a corresponding weight which appear on "Manage Display" page.

```
a: 6: {
    s: 5: "label";
    s: 7: "Address";
    s: 8: "required";
    b: 1;
    s: 6: "widget";
    a: 4: {
        s: 4: "type";
        s: 21: "addressfield_standard";
        s: 6: * * "weight";
        i: -10 * * ;
        s: 8: "settings";
        a: 2: {
            s: 15: "format_handlers";
            a: 2: {
                i: 0;
                s: 7: "address";
                i: 1;
                s: 12: "name-oneline";
            }
            s: 19: "available_countries";
            a: 0: {}
        }
        s: 6: "module";
        s: 12: "addressfield";
    }
    s: 7: "display";
    a: 3: {
        s: 7: "default";
        a: 5: {
            s: 5: "label";
            s: 6: "hidden";
            s: 4: "type";
            s: 20: "addressfield_default";
            s: 6: "weight";
            i: -10;
            s: 8: "settings";
            a: 2: {
                s: 19: "use_widget_handlers";
                i: 1;
                s: 15: "format_handlers";
                a: 1: {
                    i: 0;
                    s: 7: "address";
                }
            }
            s: 6: "module";
            s: 12: "addressfield";
        }
        s: 8: "customer";
        a: 5: {
            s: 5: "label";
            s: 6: "hidden";
            s: 4: "type";
            s: 20: "addressfield_default";
            s: 6: "weight";
            i: -10;
            s: 8: "settings";
            a: 2: {
                s: 19: "use_widget_handlers";
                i: 1;
                s: 15: "format_handlers";
                a: 1: {
                    i: 0;
                    s: 7: "address";
                }
            }
            s: 6: "module";
            s: 12: "addressfield";
        }
        s: 13: "administrator";
        a: 5: {
            s: 5: "label";
            s: 6: "hidden";
            s: 4: "type";
            s: 20: "addressfield_default";
            s: 6: "weight";
            i: -10;
            s: 8: "settings";
            a: 2: {
                s: 19: "use_widget_handlers";
                i: 1;
                s: 15: "format_handlers";
                a: 1: {
                    i: 0;
                    s: 7: "address";
                }
            }
            s: 6: "module";
            s: 12: "addressfield";
        }
    }
    s: 8: "settings";
    a: 1: {
        s: 18: "user_register_form";
        b: 0;
    }
    s: 11: "description";
    s: 0: "";
}
```

Neerav Mehta

[Drupal Developer](http://redcrackle.com)